# Is there is any way to use arcore in all device?

Tags: android, arcore

i want to use google [arcore](https://developers.google.com/ar) in all device with android development.
is there is possible with [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces)? thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean: is it possible to use "Face detection" with "arcore" in the same application?

Comment: no i mean google arcore work in all device??any other way to use that feature...

Answer (score 0):

ARCore requires devices to support some specific functionality, particularly around camera tracking and motion sensors, and Google test and certify devices to ensure it works.

They do this to ensure the user has a decent experience on the device:

> Certification is important because we want users to have a good experience with your AR application. This is primarily related to sensitive motion tracking, which is done by combining the camera image and the motion sensor input to determine how the user's device moves through the real world.
>
> To certify each device, we check the quality of the camera, motion sensors, and the design architecture to ensure it performs as expected. Also, the device needs to have a powerful enough CPU that integrates with the hardware design to ensure good performance and effective real-time calculations.

They provide a list of supported devices here: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

There are some online guides to add ARCore to a rooted Android devices which can reportedly be used on any Android device, but you are definitely going away from the mainstream here and you may find performance and troubleshooting is too much overhead.